# Single output for 2 sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Transactions`:

```
Date1          CardID     AverageBalance       TotalBalance
-----------------------------------------------------------
28-11-2013      12345         600                1200
27-11-2013      12345         100                200
26-11-2013      12345         200                400
25-11-2013      12345         300                400
```

From the above table I need to get output in such a way that average balance on 28-11-2013 is greater than the previous days i.e. on 27,26 & 25 november and the way I am taking out the average for last 2 days is I am calculating total balance for the next days excluding 28-11-2014 and checking whether the average is greater than the trice of the average of total; transaction from previous day

```
SELECT AverageBalance
FROM Transactions (nolock)
WHERE CardId = '12345'
  AND DATE1 = '2014-11-28 ') >
SELECT 
     (SELECT SUM(TotalBalance)
      FROM Transactions (nolock)
      WHERE CardId = '12345'
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Date1, '2014-11-28') >= 1) * 3)
```

Please let me know how to get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Let me focus on this:  "average balance on 28-11-2013 is greater than the previous days i.e. on 27,26 & 25 november".  Otherwise, the question doesn't make much sense to me.

I cannot tell if you want the previous two days, or all days.  For the previous two days, you would use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(averagebalance) over (partition by cardid order by date) as ab1,
             lag(averagebalance, 2) over (partition by cardid order by date) as ab2
      from transactions t
     ) t
where t.averagebalance > ab1 and t.averageblance > ab2;
```

Comment: Calculate average based on the last three days total transaciton/3

Comment: (total transaction/3) * 2